# Чем :: отличается от . ?

Tags: классы, c++

```
class student{
public:
  int hours;
  void vs(int l){
   hours += l*hours;
  }
}
student st1,st2;

//в чем различие (1) и (2)?
//(1)
st1.hours=10
st1.vs(5);

//(2)
st2::hours=20;
st2::vs(3);
```

Comment: Скажите, а второй вариант вообще работает?
Вообще, :: - оператор расширения области видимости. 
возможно что разработчики добавили такую возможность обращаться к членам класса, или использование этого оператора в таком виде не противоречит логике его работы. 
Но в любом случае точка - это оператор доступа к члену/методу класса, и для этой цели стоит использовать именно его. Код будет понятней.

Answer (score 6):

:: отделяет имя **класса** от имени определенного в нем типа или члена (переменной, функции или константы). В данном случае имя класса выступает как пространство имен.

. отделяет имя **объекта** (т.е. экземпляра класса) от имени  члена: переменной, функции или константы.

В Вашем примере второй вариант ошибочен, т.к. Вы пытаетесь использовать имя объекта там, где должно быть использовано имя класса.

Comment: Насчет `::` - не соглашусь. Есть контр-примеры.

1. Вызов нестатической ф-ции из базового класса.
2. Определение не-inline ф-ций-членов класса.

Comment: В общем, согласен. Когда имеем дело с классом, используется ::. Когда с объектом - точка.

Comment: Да, в этом отношении "+". Еще добавить, что в данном ключе класс=структура

Comment: @gecube, код автора с st2:: в любом случае не компилируется. (даже если пропущенные `';'` проставить)

Comment: @avp, согласен. Для этого нужны доп. условия

Answer (score 4):

Различие между тем, что

`.` - оператор селектор члена-класса (структуры).

Мы его используем так:

```
 struct x {int y;}
 ...
 x my_x, *my_p_x;
 ...
 my_x.y = 10;
 (*my_p_x).y = 2; // эквивалентно my_p_x->y = 2, если оператор -> не перегружен
```

`::` - оператор выбора namespace. При этом `class`, `struct` создают свое пространство имен.

```
 namespace x {int y;}
 struct x {int y;}  // ERROR! пространство имен x уже определено
 ...
 x::y = 10;
 ...
 int k;
 void func ()
 {
     int k;
     k = 10; // локальная переменная
     ::k = 2; // присваиваем 2 переменной глобальной
 }
```

Оба оператора нельзя перегрузить!!!

Answer (score 3):

Вы, вероятно, на плюсах пишете? В таком случае, оператор "." (точка) - это оператор доступа к членам класса (структуры) А "::" (двойное двоеточие) - оператор разрешения области видимости. То есть первый оператор можно применять к экземплярам, а второй - к типам и пространствам имен. В вашем примере строки  после //(2) некорректны - вы пытаетесь обратиться из экземпляра класса к его методам. Чтобы этот код был правильным, надо написать следующее:

student::vs(3);

но и сейчас он все еще некорректен, так как здесь происходит попытка обращения к нестатическому методу vs(). Чтобы код был правильным, нужно объявить vs статическим (и не использовать в его теле обращение к нестатическому полю hours)